# Logback configuration for a Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, tomcat, war, logback, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to build a simple webapp, however, I am not using the embedded Tomcat container.  Instead, I am building a .war file and deploying manually to a Tomcat 7 instance.

I am using Logback with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="./logs/jcme.log" />
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <!-- 3rd Party Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.quartz" level="INFO" />
</configuration>
```

When running the .war file inside Tomcat running in Eclipse, the log appends properly to both STDOUT and FILE appenders as configured in "../logback/base.xml".

However, when deploying this to an external Tomcat container, the "jcme.log" file is created, but is empty.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491064/spring-boot-logging-configuration-when-deployed-as-war/25528414#25528414). I had the same issue and created a setenv.bat file in my /bin with following code and it worked:

```
    set logging.config=classpath:/logback.xml
```