# spring boot war log4j2

Tags: tomcat, logging, spring-boot

i'm developing a application using spring boot version 1.3.5 (spring 4.2.6).
i use log4j2 version 2.4.1 as logging system.
when working on sts (spring tool suite) and executing on embeeded tomcat, the logs works fine (on console and on file) but when building a war file and deploying it on external tomcat 8 the log file is created but my logs don't appear in it.

i've looked for similar issue and tested some solutions:

1. setting the logging.config property on tomcat
2. configuring 'application.properties' file with the parameter logging.config=classpath:log4j2-spring.xml
3. using another logging framework (logback)

but none of this solution work. 
the post that talks about that is:
[Spring-Boot Logging configuration when deployed as .war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491064/spring-boot-logging-configuration-when-deployed-as-war)

any help or detailled answer please.

Comment: If you look inside the war file, is log4j2.xml under WEB-INF/classes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure log4j for your Spring Boot application inside Tomcat, this documentation may help you :

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Using_Log4j

> **Using Log4j**
>
> This section explains how to configure Tomcat to use log4j rather than
>   `java.util.logging` for all Tomcat's internal logging.
>
> Note: The steps described in this section are needed when you want to
>   reconfigure Tomcat to use Apache log4j for its own logging. These
>   steps are not needed if you just want to use log4j in your own web
>   application. — In that case, just put `log4j.jar` and
>   `log4j.properties` into `WEB-INF/lib` and `WEB-INF/classes` of your
>   web application.
>
> The following steps describe configuring log4j to output Tomcat's
>   internal logging.
>
> Create a file called `log4j.properties` with the following content and
>   save it into `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`

Comment: i don t want to configure log4j to be tomcat's logging system but i want it to be my spring boot's application logging system.